# Faster technique to read a .txt file in a loop

Tags: c++, oop, opencv

I would like to improve the performance of my porgram. The problem is following:

- I have a computer vision app that works only when a parameter X<10
- X is given by another programm that uses a sensor to provide the value of X each 5 seconds in a .txt file.
- In the CV app I use a camera capture within a `while(1)` loop.
- Now I am reading in each iteration a .txt file that contains the value of X and if X<10 the CV programm runs but in each iteration it verifies if X is still < 10; if X>10 the CV app should stop and close.
- The performance of reading the txt in each iteration is lower, so I am looking for a technique to verify X value in a more efficient way.
- I am using, opencv, C++ in a raspberry pi.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure reading the text file is the bottleneck? How are you reading it currently?

Comment: In other words less-thinly veiled. update your question and *post your read code as you have it now* .

Comment: This seems like a highly, highly inefficient way of sharing parameters. There is surely another way..

Comment: You definitely need a better way of Inter-process communication or whatever it is you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: You mention the other application is a python script. Does is need to be a separate process? You could embed Python using boost.Python, and run the script in a separate thread. Or even a script that will do IPC with the other Python app, at least giving you the same language on both sides.

Comment: can you post your code of reading the file? do you have any idea why reading becomes slower in each iteration? maybe you should read the file in a different thread to not block your real-time processing with thr io operation. if you have access to both programs you should use real inter process communication like gRPC, Apache Thrift or similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways of sharing data between processes (commonly called interprocess communication, or IPC). I would recommend to have a look at Boost C++ library's different options, any of them should be a lot faster than your current solution. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/interprocess.html

It shouldn't be a problem to build Boost for ARM.

Comment: Thanks, that can help, is there any issue If the IPC is between a Python Script and a c++ compiled program?

Comment: It will make things more complicated. You will need to find a library for both C++ and Python that uses the same IPC mechanism and is possible to build on ARM. I recon the BSD socket interface is what you should look for.